# Serializing Delta<T> to JSON

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an API PATCH endpoint that receives a `Delta<T>` and I need to serialize it, put it on a queue, and deserialize it in another process.

Using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` returns `{}`. The incoming `Delta<T>` looks like it's correctly formed.

Any idea why `Delta<T>` is serializing to an empty JSON object?

**UPDATE**

- Using `System.Web.OData.Delta<T>` gives me `{}`.
- Using `System.Web.Http.OData.Delta<T>` gives me a full serialization of `T`, including unchanged properties.

Comment: Running into the exact same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using `System.Web.OData.Delta<T>` gives me `{}`.
- Using `System.Web.Http.OData.Delta<T>` gives me a full serialization of `T`, including unchanged properties.